# Angular Guard and JWT

Tags: angular, angular-guards

I am trying to do the next... i have an API where i send a JWT token by POST to be verified if it is valid/expired,

so in my angular login service i have a method like this.

```
isUserlogged() {
  return this.httpClient.get(`${this.URL}/verifyToken`, { headers: { 'authorization': localStorage.getItem('token') } })   
}
```

this subscription returns a boolean, all ok here.

Now i am implementing Guards in my app, so now i want to use that boolean value for my canActivate method to block the access... i read that i need to return, true or false in this method to allow or block the access to the routes that i configured before

So i am doing something like this inside of canActivate.

```
this.loginService.isUserlogged().subscribe((response: boolean)=>{  

if(response){
   return true;
}
   return false;
});
```

but this is returning void... why? how can i retreive the true or false value from this subscription?

Comment: try just returning `this.loginService.isUserlogged()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't return a subscription from inside a route a guard, If not boolean then return an Observable of boolean.

```
return this.loginService.isUserlogged()
```

Since "isUserlogged" is already giving you a boolean output here, you can directly return the Observable.

If `isUserlogged()` is not returning a boolean then pipe it.

```
return this.loginService.isUserlogged().pipe(
    map((resp) => {
        // some logic here, check the return.
        // based on the logic
        if (something) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    })
)
```

This will all work if your `API` call is getting finished and returning a proper response. If your API is returning void, then you have not provided any details regarding your API call and your API works. (First test your API with an HTTP client, like: Postman, if that is giving a proper response then integrate it with Angular)

Comment: isUserlogged is not returning a boolean... there is where i have the problem i think...

Comment: this._login.isUserlogged().subscribe((response: Observable<boolean>) => {
      
      return response;

    })

Comment: @SergioCano: Check the updated answer. And Where are you doing the `subscribe()`. You shouldn't do a subscribe in `canActivate()`. Anyway log `response`in your `subscribe` and tell me what do you see.

Comment: my API is checked with postman and even in angular i log the response and i receive, true/false depending if token is valid or not... so let me try the piece of code that you updated.

Comment: is map, imported by rxjs? sorry i am new in angular

Comment: @SergioCano `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'`

Comment: i am using the piece of code that you sent me, i have response in a log, and is loggin true or false... perfectly, i have return response... so in my canActivate i have... this.loginService.isUserlogged()... but i have an error, do i have tu subscribe after or something?... jesus i am stuck here :(

Comment: with your code, isUserlogged(), is returning an Observable. but canActivate only accept booleans... so how can i change it?

Comment: @SergioCano canActivate method accepts both boolean and observable of type boolean. so, you can return observable of type boolean

Comment: @SergioCano canAtivate() returns a lot a of things: https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate. In your case, make your code someting like: `canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {...}`

Comment: wow finally, yea adding what is returning canActivate it is working... damn this sintax ... THANKS A LOT !!!

Answer (score 0):

My solutions, Promise Method and a healthy running guard.

```js
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    return this.mailVerifyControl()
      .then(() => {
        return true;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return false;
      });
  }


  mailVerifyControl(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (this.authService.isMailVerified === true) {
        reject()
      }
      resolve();
    });
  }
```